# How do I display a custom view with Spring MVC in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a simple Jakarta EE demo application in IntelliJ using Maven as my build system, Spring's MVC framework, and Tomcat 9.0.70.0 as my local deployment server.

The application comes with the default `index.jsp` file within the `webapp` folder, which is displayed properly when I launch my app in Tomcat.

[image]

I have created an additional spring-config file, `spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml`, in addition to altering the default `web.xml` file inside the `webapp/WEB-INF/` folder. The code for each is displayed below.

**spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.mvc" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I wanted to create a new Controller called **HomeController** that would display a custom view, `main-menu.jsp`, stored in folder that would hold all of my views within the **webapp** directory.

**Project directory**

[image]

**HomeController**

```
package com.luv2code.mvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHomePage() { return "main-menu"; }
}
```

**main-menu.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Spring MVC Demo - Home Page</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, adding these two new files resulted in no change when I ran the application again with Tomcat. I have since tried the following with no success:

1. Deleting the index.jsp file altogether
2. Moving `main-menu.jsp` to the root `webapp` folder
3. Changing the `@RequestMapping` annotation to use "/home" instead of just "/" and appending *home* to my app URL.
4. Appending a `<a>` tag to the `<body>` element of index.jsp and providing the name of my custom view for its `href` attribute, and then try to navigate to my view by clicking the link.
5. 

All I end up getting is Tomcat's custom 404 error page.

[image]

Comment: swap the name of the xml files

Comment: I tried, there was no change.